# linearly independent sets of an abelian free group of finite rank

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I am working on my course on free abelian groups of finite rank: the definition (it's more a theorem) is

> Abelian free group of rank $n$:= An abelian group that is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}^n$ for $n\in\Bbb{N}.$

Now I am assuming the following result, *lemma*: for any matrix $A\in\mathcal{M}_{r\times n}(\Bbb{Z})$ there exists $P$(respectively $Q$) in $\mathcal{GL}(r,\Bbb{Z})$ $\bigl($respectively $\mathcal{GL}(n,\Bbb{Z})\bigr)$ such that [image]

And we havev $d_1\mid d_2\mid \cdots\mid d_s$

Now, I would like to use this to prove that all basis have the same rank.

So I just need to prove that for any linearly independent sets of $G$ must has at most $r$ elements.

So given a basis $(x_1,\cdots,x_r)$ of $G$, we take a family $(y_1,\cdots,y_n)$, then $y_j=\sum_{i=1}^r a_{i,j}x_i$ wich means that we have a $r\times n$ matrix, call it $A$.

By the lemma we have exactly the matrix as described above.

> I am not sure how can I continue here ?

Comment: I have edited your question with the correct name of such groups.

Comment: @Crostul Merci!

Comment: ??? I don't see the point of proving this, as the theorem is true for *any* commutative ring. It has nothing to see with *invariant factors*.

Comment: @Bernard ???? Isn't a theorem that all basis of free abelian group have the same number of elements ? I didn't choose to prove it with the 'lemma' it's in my course as result of 'it'. Of course it's the same as $\Bbb{Z}^n\simeq\Bbb{Z}^r$ is equivalent to $n=r$.

Comment: But abelian  groups are $\mathbf Z$-modules, so it's a particular case of a general result. If you want to prove it only in this case, just tensor be $\mathbf Q$, and it comes down to the case of vector spaces.

Comment: @Bernard I saw that theorem much before having known what "tensoring with $\mathbf{Q}$" is, precisely I saw a quite complicated proof based on induction. Here, you don't even need to know what a ring is to get the result.

Comment: @Crostul yep, I am exactly in this case.